# How can I stop a Galaxy S7 from connecting to multiple Bluetooth sources?

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-s7, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

In my front room I've got a Bluetooth sound bar under the TV. I also have a portable Bluetooth speaker that I use around the house a lot, mostly in the kitchen.

However the reception from my sound bar weakly reached the kitchen. So when I'm listening to music while moving round preparing food, my phone regularly picks up the sound bar and connects to that too. When that happens the music stops and neither device plays. I have to turn Bluetooth off and on again and reconnect to the portable speaker.

This is super annoying and I find it hard to believe there's no setting to turn off multiple connections or auto connect to stop it happening. Is there anything I can change so that my phone will stick to one Bluetooth device at a time?

Comment: Search Play Store for apps. [This one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tom.bluetoothDevicesWidget) seems to fit your needs, since tapping a widget would connect

Comment: @beeshyams thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to stop my phone connecting to multiple other devices?